# Open and Close jquery dialog from code behiend in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-dialog

i have a `jquery dialog` which is open on every page load. `jquery dialog` contain a close button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "Create your free showcase profile",
            autoOpen: true,
            hide: 'fold',
            show: 'blind',
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Now what i am trying to do is , when the dialog was closed by the user by clicking the `Close` button , it would not visible again to user till the end of session.

please help to achieve this

Comment: please try script manager in this case.

Comment: You could save a flag in a cookie or in `localStorage` with the session id. Whenever your pages load, just check if the you already set a flag for the current session. If yes, don't show the dialog.

Comment: @AndreiV i appreciate your answer but how to achieve this , how i create create the close button click event ?

Comment: More or less in the lines of Kartikeya's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `localStorage` and store a token value in it and then check `localstorage` as shown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
var $dialog =   $("div").dialog({
        title: "Create your free showcase profile",
        autoOpen: false,
        hide: 'fold',
        show: 'blind',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                localStorage.setItem('token','closed');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    }).dialog('open');  //trigger on page load


     var init =  setInterval(function () {
         if(localStorage.getItem('token') == 'closed')
         {
             clearInterval(init);
             return;
         }
         $dialog.dialog('open');
      }, 10000);
});
```

OR use `sessionStorage` as shown :

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
var $dialog =   $("div").dialog({
        title: "Create your free showcase profile",
        autoOpen: false,
        hide: 'fold',
        show: 'blind',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                sessionStorage.setItem('token','closed');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    }).dialog('open');  //trigger on page load


     var init =  setInterval(function () {
         if(sessionStorage.getItem('token') == 'closed')
         {
             clearInterval(init);
             return;
         }
         $dialog.dialog('open');
      }, 10000);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zvt2u20/2/)

Comment: This is incomplete. Consider what would happen if the user were to close their browser, open it again and go to website again. The `token` is already there... You should either delete it (on tab/window close) or save the session id instead of `open`.

Comment: @Kartikeya in which place i put the `localStorage` code ?

Comment: @GarimaRawat...the complete code is shown above with localstorage

Comment: @AndreiV..yes good point ... i have use sessionstorage which looses its value on browser close event,,

Comment: @Kartikeya its working fine but whhen i press the close button the Dialog showing again. after page load its working fine.

Comment: @GarimaRawat...this is not possible just check you code with my code carefully.

Comment: @Kartikeya i am already using your code i was just copy and paste Your code to my project

Comment: @GarimaRawat..if possible plz provide fiddle link so that i can correct any mistake in the code...